# Кадрировать изображение по границам объекта внутри него в PHP

Tags: php, изображения, gd

Есть ли что-нибудь на PHP позволяющее обрезать изображения по контуру объекта в нём?

Т.е. к примеру у нас есть логотип в формате JPEG/PNG/GIF на белом/прозрачном фоне, нужно автоматически обрезать фон вокруг объекта до границ самого объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть два пути.

1. ImageMagic и функцию convert (По скорости должно быть лучше)
2. Перебирать по пикселям и искать "не пустой" (Тут больше свободы но более медленный способ)

На PHP будет где-то так (Код не оптимизирован)

```
function CropEmpty($src, $dst) {
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($src));
    imagealphablending($image, false);
    imagesavealpha($image, true);

    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);

    //Находим верхнюю крайнюю точку
    for ($top = 0; $top < $height; $top++) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
            if (imagecolorat($image, $x, $top)) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    //Находим нижнюю крайнюю точку
    for ($bottom = 0; $bottom < $height; $bottom++) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
            if (imagecolorat($image, $x, $height - $bottom - 1)) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    //Находим крайнюю левую точку
    for ($left = 0; $left < $width; $left++) {
        for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
            if (imagecolorat($image, $left, $y)) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    //Находим крайнюю правую точку
    for ($right = 0; $right < $width; $right++) {
        for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
            if (imagecolorat($image, $width - $right - 1, $y)) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    #region newImage

    $newWidth = $width - ($left + $right);
    $newHeight = $height - ($top + $bottom);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagealphablending($newImage, false);
    imagesavealpha($newImage, true);
    imagefilledrectangle($newImage, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, imagecolorallocatealpha($newImage, 255, 255, 255, 127));
    imagecopy($newImage, $image, 0, 0, $left, $top, $newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagepng($newImage, $dst);
    imagedestroy($newImage);

    #endregion

    imagedestroy($image);
}

CropEmpty('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png', __DIR__ . '/test.png');
```

Ну и пример с тримом

```
    $im = new Imagick($src);
    $im->trimImage(0); //Погрешность цвета
    $im->writeImage($dst);
```

Comment: пробовал Ваш алгоритм, не работает у меня.. не понятно что он вообще сделал с изображением, размер файла на выходе увеличен, размеры по пиксельно остались те же.

Comment: про ImageMagic, имелось ввиду: Imagick::trimImage ???

Comment: Ссылку на исходную картинку в студию

Comment: Скорее всего она у вас в jpeg формате, а следовательно png занимает больше места, так как является форматом без потери качества в отличии от jpeg. И не имеет прозрачности, а мой алгоритм как раз отсекает прозрачные пиксели.  0хFFFFFF как бы белый и проходит по условию. Думаю вы сможете доработать его для своих нужд. Добавить сохранения в нужный формат и те цвета которые нужно считать пустыми. Думаю необходимо будет учитывать и схожие цвета. Для человеческого глаза 0хFEFEFE выглядит тоже белым но в условии может не пройти)))

Comment: перешел на использование convert  - всё устраивает, спасибо вам за совет!

Comment: Если ImageMagic устраивает. То да. Это лучший вариант.